# Timer and Buttons Issues

Tags: c#, button, timer

I'm doing a project using Visual Studio 2013 using C#. I want the timer to countdown from 120 minutes to 0 minutes and when it reaches 0, a message box will show that the time is up. I also want the timer to reset when the reset button is pressed. However, when I pressed the reset button, even though the timer is reset, I pressed the start button and the message box "Time's up" would appear and the timer would not start. Please help me. I'm a total newbie to C# so please try not to give me complicated answers that is hard to understand. Also, you will see me around a lot more because I'll have more questions to ask. Thanks!! (This are my codes.)

```
    private void startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = true;
        foreach (var button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            button.Click += button_Click;
            timer.Start();
            button.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
        }
    }

    private void stopandresetbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button.BackColor = default(Color);
        timer.Stop();
        timeleft = 0;
        timerlabel.Hide();
    }

    int timeleft = 120;
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timeleft > -1)
        {
            timerlabel.Text = timeleft + " minutes";
            timeleft = timeleft - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Time's up!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you looping through all buttons?

Comment: Try making use of the timer's interval property.  
Please show the code for  button_Click;

Comment: @kirsteng I think he has already set the Interval because he said that it worked the first time.

Comment: This question could be better worded. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour  again on how to word a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is at the `stopandresetbutton_Click` method. You should not set the timeLeft variable to 0. Because you want to *reset* the timer, you should set it to 120 (If your unit is mins).

**OR**

You set the timeLeft variable to 120 in the `startbutton_Click` method. That way it works as well

**For a better approach**

You can write a property like this

```
private int TimeLeft {
    get {return timeLeft; }
    set {
        timeLeft = value;
        timerlabel.Text = timeleft + " minutes";
    }
}
```

That way you can set `TimeLeft` to some value and the label's text will change as well. This is because you might not remember to change the label's text after you set the value of timeLeft.